# Meaning of reg expression in drop.conf (Suricata)

Tags: regular-expression

I have this question since time ago, and I'm not able to understand it.
In the sample config file for Suricata drop rules, drop.conf, appears this sample line:

```
# Rules matching specifiers in this file will be converted to drop rules.
#
# Examples:
#
# 1:2019401
# 2019401
#
# re:heartbleed
# re:MS(0[7-9]|10)-\d+
```

What means the last line's expression? `MS(0[7-9]|10)-\d+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex `MS(0[7-9]|10)-\d+` means:

`MS` : literal `MS` string.
`[7-9]` : character class of characters between `7` and `9`, inclusive, so either of these: `7`, `8`, or `9`.
`(0[7-9]|10)` : either of these: `07`, `08`, `09` or `10`.
`-` : literal dash (`-`).
`\d+` : 1 or more digits, that is more than one occurrence of any of `0`-`9`.

This matches, for example:

```
MS07-2
MS10-13
```

This does not match, for example:

```
MS06-2
MS10-i3
```

For the Perl flavor of regular expressions (note that there are other regex flavors), see:

- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: Awesome, now I understand that it refers to the Microsoft vulnerability codes, for example MS08-067: Microsoft Windows Server Service Crafted RPC Request Handling Remote Code Execution